# mysql show rows in order from highest value to lowest value

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table that contains a column named views. Each time the user refreshes the page, it updates the view count +1.
What im trying to do, is create a mysql query to output the list of rows based on their views count, from highest to lowest.

this is what i thought would work

```
SELECT * FROM picdb ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 10
```

even when i view it ASCENDING, its all out of whack.

thoughts?

**EDIT**
the column type is TEXT

**SOLVED**  changed column type to INT and it works fine now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: What is the date type of the views column?

Comment: forgot to mention that...post updated

Comment: Why is the column type text? Will there ever be anything other than a number in there? If it was a number field, it would probably order correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your column type is TEXT, the default sorting behavior treats the data as strings, and therefore sorts them alphabetically (not numerically).

Change your column type to a number type, and it will sort correctly.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tbl
ORDER BY
    CAST(views AS UNSIGNED) DESC
LIMIT
    10
```

Might do the trick. The real question is why you have a column containing integers with the text type?

Comment: Thank you so much, you rescued me!

Answer (score 1):

```
select a,b,CAST(views AS UNSIGNED) c from picdb order by c desc limit 10
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the classic alphanumeric sort problem. If the column type is text, then you are probably seeing order like 1, 10, 15, 20, 3. In other words, it’s sorting by the text value instead of the integer value.

You could change the column to a numeric type, or you could do:

```
SELECT * FROM picdb ORDER BY CONVERT(views, UNSIGNED INTEGER) DESC LIMIT 10
```

However, this would not be able to take advantage of any index on the `views` column. It would be better to change the column to a numeric type if that is indeed what it represents.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your table rows from ***higher value to lower value*** then use this query.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM CurrencyTable ORDER BY CAST(currency_rate AS UNSIGNED) DESC";
```

And if you want to show rows from ***lower value to higher value*** then use this query

```
query-2 = "SELECT * FROM CurrencyTable ORDER BY CAST(currency_rate AS UNSIGNED) ASC";
```